# Import_logs.py fails when trying to parse a big apache access log (bigger than 900 MB)

Tags: apache, mariadb, matomo

I am trying to parse big apache logs but import_logs.py fails with this error:

2017-01-23 18:30:39,245: [INFO] Max number of attempts reached, server is unreachable!_

> Fatal error: HTTP Error 500 Internal Server Error, response:
>
> {"status":"error","tracked":0,"invalid":0,"invalidindices":[]}_ You
>
> can restart the import of
>
> "/awdata/piwik/cosmote/geratgweb04/www.cosmote.grwith_ssl-access.log-20170123"
> from the point it failed by specifying --skip=78454 on the command
> line.

I use a VM with 8 cpus and 8 gb mem.

My OS version is RHEL 7.3,

with  apache version is Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux),

php is PHP 7.0.14 and mariadb version is 5.5.52
Piwik version 3.0.1

The command I am using is:

```
/var/www/html/zak/piwik/misc/log-analytics/import_logs.py --url=http://middlinf.ote.gr:81/piwik/ --idsite=6 --recorders=8 --enable-http-errors --enable-http-redirects --enable-static /awdata/piwik/cosmote/geratgweb04/www.cosmote.gr_with_ssl-access.log-20170123 --retry-max-attempts=20
```

Apache error log is showing:

[Tue Jan 24 13:44:33.855134 2017] [:error] [pid 17456:tid 140544525190912] [client 172.18.20.26:16610] Error in Piwik (tracker): Error query: SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction In query:

```
UPDATE piwik_log_visit SET idvisitor = ?, user_id = ?,
    visit_last_action_time = ?, visit_exit_idaction_url = ?,
    visit_total_actions = visit_total_actions + 1 ,
    visit_total_interactions = visit_total_interactions + 1 ,
    visit_total_time = ?
    WHERE idsite = ? AND idvisit = ?
```

Parameters: array ( 0 => ' \xa6\x96\xbc\xef\xb9\xde\xf5', 1 => '""', 2 => '2017-01-23 08:14:43', 3 => 47298, 4 => 0, 5 => 4, 6 => 11224, )

And:

[Tue Jan 24 13:51:58.582401 2017] [:error] [pid 18419:tid 140544525190912] [client 172.18.20.26:18232] Error in Piwik (tracker): Error query: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction In query:

```
UPDATE piwik_log_visit SET idvisitor = ?, user_id = ?,
    visit_last_action_time = ?, visit_exit_idaction_url = ?,
    visit_total_actions = visit_total_actions + 1 ,
    visit_total_interactions = visit_total_interactions + 1 ,
    visit_total_time = ?
    WHERE idsite = ? AND idvisit = ?
```

Parameters: array ( 0 => ' \xa6\x96\xbc\xef\xb9\xde\xf5', 1 => '""', 2 => '2017-01-23 08:42:33', 3 => 49791, 4 => 242, 5 => 4, 6 => 11371, )>

> ```
> and mariadb log is showing:
>
> Time: 170123 18:00:46
> User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
> Thread_id: 1691 Schema: piwik_db QC_hit: No
> Query_time: 3.858223 Lock_time: 0.000060 Rows_sent: 1 Rows_examined: 1
> ```

```
     SET timestamp=1485187246;
     SELECT visit_last_action_time, visit_first_action_time, idvisitor,
 idvisit, user_id, visit_exit_idaction_url, visit_exit_idaction_name,
 visitor_returning, visitor_days_since_first, visitor_days_since_order,
 visitor_count_visits, visit_goal_buyer, location_country,
 location_region, location_city, location_latitude, location_longitude,
 referer_name, referer_keyword, referer_type, idsite,
 visit_entry_idaction_url, visit_total_actions,
 visit_total_interactions, visit_total_searches, config_device_brand,
 config_device_model, config_device_type, visit_total_events,
 visit_total_time, location_ip, location_browser_lang, custom_var_k1,
 custom_var_v1, custom_var_k2, custom_var_v2, custom_var_k3,
 custom_var_v3, custom_var_k4, custom_var_v4, custom_var_k5,
 custom_var_v5 FROM piwik_log_visit
WHERE visit_last_action_time >= '2017-01-22 05:14:21'
  AND visit_last_action_time <= '2017-01-22 06:14:21'
  AND idsite = '6' AND idvisitor = '
ORDER BY visit_last_action_time DESC
```

I did some research in the forums but did not find anything interesting.
Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

-Thanassis

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE piwik_log_visit`.  I suspect you are missing the composite

```
INDEX(idsite, idvisit)
```

(The columns can be in either order.)

For

```
WHERE visit_last_action_time >= '2017-01-22 05:14:21'
  AND visit_last_action_time <= '2017-01-22 06:14:21'
  AND idsite = '6' AND idvisitor = '
```

you need `INDEX(idsite, idvisitor, visit_last_action_time)`, being sure to have the range column last.

Did you notice that that range covers 3601 seconds?  I recommend this pattern for various reasons:

```
WHERE visit_last_action_time >= '2017-01-22 05:14:21'
  AND visit_last_action_time  < '2017-01-22 05:14:21' + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your responce. Here is the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE piwik_log_visit. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1po0mmh9oxXXmCebns9392fxRpzPHWEYGd02eyYO6HjY/edit There is no such an index indeed. I will try to create it and re-run the log import. I will update you soon. Regarding the interval pattern I am not sure how to do it since it is done interanlly from piwik command import_logs.py. It is not a custom query.

Comment: Complain to piwik.